# How to prevent attribute re-access until all attributes have been accessed once (Python metaclass)?

Tags: python, metaclass

I have a list of attributes, say `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`, and I want to write a metaclass which ensures the following properties:

- They can all be accessed once, in any order
- They cannot be accessed again until all have been accessed once

For example, the following is how it might work:

```
class TrackedAttrsMeta:
  @classmethod
  def with_attributes(cls, *args):
    cls._expected_attrs = set(args)
    return cls

class MyClass(metaclass=TrackedAttrsMeta.with_attributes("foo", "bar", "baz")):
  foo: "quux"
  bar: {"blah": -1}
  baz: 1

ob = MyClass()
for _ in range(10):
  print(ob.foo) # Allowed
  print(ob.bar) # Allowed
  print(ob.foo) # Fails with an error because "baz" has not been accessed yet
  print(ob.baz) # Would be allowed if not for above
  print(ob.foo) # Would be allowed because we've accessed every attribute in the list once
```

The implementation of a custom `__getattribute__` might look like so:

```
def _tracking_getattr(self, name):
  value = super().__getattribute__(name)
  remaining = list(expected_attrs - self._accessed_attrs)
  if name in self._accessed_attrs:
    raise ValueError(f"Already accessed '{name}', must access all of {remaining} before this is allowed again")
           
  self._accessed_attrs.add(name)

  # Once we've seen them all, clear out the record so we can see them again
  if self._accessed_attrs == expected_attrs:
    self._accessed_attrs = set()
```

Comment: This is an extremely weird thing to do, and it sounds like there's probably a better way to handle whatever underlying problem motivated you to do this.

Comment: I'm trying to debug a system where this invariant should hold (eg the object must read from certain attributes once per iteration), and I think the easiest way to do it is to force the application to crash when it happens once. I suspect certain attributes are not being accessed but don't know which, and it's tedious to do it by hand (which I'm nonetheless doing anyways)

Comment: @ijustlovemath That's why we have queryable log files and unit tests.

Comment: Sure, and that's something I have, but I'd like to catch it immediately rather than add a bunch of verbosity to the logs

Comment: Debug switch for the logging, and a test environment. And again, unit tests with stubs, harnesses, monkey patches, etc. If the constraint is critical (and not an XY Problem) I'd also challenge the design or implementation as attributes. This whole scenario is a code-smell to me.

Comment: Is the question not clear enough? What can I add to make it more clear?

Comment: So does `_tracking_getattr` not work for you? If you've answered your own question, feel free to post as an answer below.

Comment: I don't typically use metaclasses, so I think it's a bug in my understanding, but if I manage to get something to work, I will post as an answer

Comment: nonetheless, a custom `__getattribute__` should work for you - no need for a metaclass.

Comment: metaclass allows you to apply this to many classes, as needed, without boilerplate. Also allows you to update the implementation in once place as needed

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile

Comment: The question contains nonfunctional pseudocode, see "how it might work". I've posted a functional answer.

Comment: How is `ob` supposed to know when a new iteration starts, in order to "reset" the notion of which attributes are allowed to be read? Also, does an expression statement like `ob.foo` count as reading the value if the value isn't used in any way?

Comment: This question is vaguely related to the idea of linear types, where a function can be defined in such a way that one or more arguments *must* be used (and used only once) in computing the return value. (The similarity falls apart when your "function" is only implied by the structure of the loop, and the "arguments" aren't passed explicitly but just arbitrary expressions accessed in the body of the loop.)

Comment: (Another related idea is that of affine types, which involve function arguments that must be used *at most*, rather than *exactly*, one time. I'm not aware of any similar definition that involves arguments that must be used *at least* once.)

Comment: It doesn't know when a new iteration starts, but it does know which of its tracked attributes have been accessed (of course there's no way to know if the access was *used*, but I'm not sure if you can express that in Python). The invariant here is "I should not be looking at/invoking `ob.foo` until I've looked at `ob.{bar,baz}`", which can be handled completely by the metaclass

Comment: When I asked this, I believed that there were some objects in a control loop that were updating their state more than once per control cycle, and used this approach to detect and fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this metaclass like so, but it will only allow one set of "tracked" attributes per class. Instead of constructing the metaclass with a classmethod, you will add a `_tracked_` attribute as well as the metaclass to your class constructor.

```
class TrackedAttrsMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, cls_name, bases, dct):
        # Which attributes have been accessed so far
        dct["_trk_accessed_"] = set()

        # Which attributes we apply the tracking to
        tracked_attrs = dct.get("_tracked_", None)
        if tracked_attrs is None or not isinstance(tracked_attrs, list):
            raise TypeError("You must define a _tracked_ attribute on the class with the list of attributes you'd like to track")
        dct["_trk_attributes_"] = set(tracked_attrs)

        cls_instance = super().__new__(cls, cls_name, bases, dct)

        # Preserve the object's original getattr
        gtattr = cls_instance.__getattribute__

        def _tracking_getattr(cls, name):
            value = gtattr(cls, name)
            # Prevent a stackoverflow by handling these attributes specially
            if name in ["_trk_attributes_", "_trk_accessed_"]:
                return value

            if name in cls._trk_attributes_:
                remaining = list(cls._trk_attributes_ - cls._trk_accessed_)

                if name in cls._trk_accessed_:
                    raise AttributeError(f"Cannot access {name} before accessing {remaining}")

                cls._trk_accessed_.add(name)

                if cls._trk_accessed_ == cls._trk_attributes_:
                    cls._trk_accessed_.clear()

            return value

        def _allow_access(self, name):
            if name not in self._trk_attributes_:
                raise ValueError(f"Not tracking {name}")

            if name not in self._trk_accessed_:
                raise ValueError(f"Access to {name} is already allowed")

            self._trk_accessed_.remove(name)

        # Use the custom getattr
        cls_instance.__getattribute__ = _tracking_getattr

        # Add a method to skip tracking once
        cls_instance.allow_untracked_access = _allow_access

        return cls_instance
```

You can use it like this:

```
class YourClass(metaclass=TrackedAttrsMeta):
    _tracked_ = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    foo = "bah"
    bar = 2
    baz = {"h": 6}

# Example usage:
obj = YourClass()
print(obj.foo)  # Access foo for the first time
# print(obj.foo) # This will raise AttributeError
print(obj.bar)  # Access bar for the first time
print(obj.baz)  # Access baz for the first time
print(obj.foo)  # This is allowed since we've accessed all
print(obj.bar)  # This is allowed since we've accessed all

# The following will raise an AttributeError, as we just accessed bar
# print(obj.bar)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of "resetting" the object to disallow attribute access once the next iteration starts (unless the OP really has separate instances of the class in each iteration, and the loop is a red herring).

Comment: It does! See: `cls._trk_accessed_.clear()`

Comment: No, that allows repeat access in the *same* iteration once each attribute has been used. What about the next iteration?

Comment: It's the same object, so it has the same tracking information! When all tracked attributes have been seen (presumably at the end of the iteration), the object is free to access the attributes again. It's not tied in a *strict* way to the iteration, as I'm not sure how to express that. If you have some example code that you think shouldn't work but does, I can update the question/answer to address it.

Comment: You could also use this approach to implement different tracking strategies, eg enforcing an order to the access (lists instead of sets), incorporating setattr, enforcing a certain number of accesses of .foo before .bar, etc etc. This approach works for my particular use case, but also answers the overall question.

Comment: Also I believe that the question does not require specific ties to an iteration, but am open to rewording it if you have suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This really cries out for a context manager, so that you can use a `with` statement to *explicitly* delimit the block in which exhaustive access needs to be enforced. (The object itself doesn't have anyway of knowing about when one iteration of the loop ends and the next begins.)

For example,

```
ob = MyClass()

for i in range(10):
    with ob as proxy:
        print(proxy.foo)
        print(proxy.bar)
        print(proxy.baz)
```

Something like

```
class AttributeTrackerProxy:
    def __init__(self, obj, *args):
        self.obj = obj
        self._unused = set(args)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if self._unused and name not in self._unused:
            # i.e., if there are unused attributes and "name" isn't one of them...
            raise Exception(f"{name} already used; access others first") 
        self._unused.remove(name)
        return getattr(self.obj, name)


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = ...
        self.bar = ...
        self.baz = ...
        self._attrs = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

    def __enter__(self):
        self._proxy = AttributeTrackerProxy(self._attrs)
        return self._proxy

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # There isn't really anything to do here, unless
        # you want to raise an exception if self._proxy._unused
        # hasn't been emptied.
        pass
```

The only thing the metaclass would help with is automating the definition of the list of attribute names. (`__enter__` could be defined by a mix-in class and inherited by `MyClass`.) I would not recommend complicating your code with a metaclass; just define `_attrs` manually.

Comment: How would this work with multiple objects? Can you merge context managers, or would you have to have one with statement for each object you want to track? One advantage of the metaclass is that I don't have to rework existing loops, only the class definition of the objects in the loops

Comment: This also still allows "misuse" of the objects if theres a section of code you forgot to wrap in a `with` statement. The ultimate goal is to detect use errors no matter where the object is used

Comment: Your existing loops *should* be reworked, because there is no way for an object to identify when a new loop iteration begins.

Comment: My use case is for detection of programming errors, to facilitate bug fixes and refactors. Use of a with statement for that purpose implies I already know where the errors are occurring, instead of building tools to help me find and fix the errors. Does it make sense why this approach would be circular in that case?

Comment: I also am very curious to understand how this would work with multiple objects/merging context managers. If you have a solution there, feel free to edit!

Comment: In that case, I would do this with a 3rd-party analysis tool, not try to detect the error at runtime. (Basically, parse the code and work with the resulting AST.)

Comment: When I feel metaclasses have failed me, that will be my next step :) or, more likely, rewriting in a language where you can express API misuse directly in the type system. For now, the solution has already paid dividends!